# solving trigonometric equations taking all solutions

Tags: matlab

How can I solve trigonometric equations without loosing all the solutions in matlab ? For example :

```
solve(sin(theta) == 0, theta)
```

will return `0` but I want to know all the solutions, not only the first one.

Comment: You know there's infinite solutions to that, right? ;)

Comment: For the particular equations I posted , yes.  But for more complex equations things get more strange and unpredictable and it's dangerous to see only one solution. At least I want to know that there are many solutions. Without plotting. In most cases only solutions beetween -2pi and 2pi are required.

Answer (score 3):

You can add some conditions to your equation.

For example start by declaring a symbolic variable theta:

```
syms theta
```

And now add as many conditions as you need:

```
solve(sin(theta) == 0,theta>=-2*pi,theta<=2*pi, theta)
```

You can also set assumption on symbolic variable, it is more clear in my opinion.

```
assume(-2*pi <= theta <= 2*pi)
out = solve(sin(theta) == 0, theta)
```

In both case the **output** will be:

```
out =

     0
    pi
   -pi
 -2*pi
  2*pi
```

If needed, you can order the result with:

```
sym(sort(double(out)))
```